# Why echo isn't able to access a variable in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ip, echo, squid

I can't find anything that helps with this issue even if the answer may be very simple.

I'm trying to get squid to redirect traffic through a 3g dongle, therefore I need to table the IP and change it in the squid.conf every time it changes.

I'm using this code here on "/etc/ppp/ip-up.local" so it's launched every time a new IP connects (or reconnects) to the machine.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$PPP_IFACE" == "ppp0" ]] ; then
        TABLE=uplink2
        /bin/sed -i "s&\(tcp_outgoing_address\).*\(very1\)&\1 $PPP_LOCAL \2&" /etc/squid/squid.conf
fi

##generate ip subnet for route
baseip=`echo "$PPP_LOCAL" | cut -d"." -f1-3`

/usr/sbin/ip route add "$baseip".0/24 dev "$PPP_IFACE" src "$PPP_LOCAL" table "$TABLE"
/usr/sbin/ip route add default via "$PPP_REMOTE" table "$TABLE"
/usr/sbin/ip rule add from "$PPP_LOCAL" table "$TABLE"

/usr/sbin/squid/ -k reconfigure
/usr/bin/systemctl squid restart

exit 0
```

**The problem is that  `baseip=echo "$PPP_LOCAL" | cut -d"." -f1-3` cannot use $PPP_LOCAL**

I tried to add `echo $PPP_LOCAL >> file.txt` but it just adds an empty line.

It's awkward to me that sed instead accesses the variable and modify correctly the squid.conf file with the new address

How can I fix this??

I also have a "sub-question", I'm a complete newbie just starting to learn and I'm not sure whether or not I should add an ip-down code to remove the table rules

Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: I don't see an assigment to PPP_LOCAL before you use it. Am I missing something? If it is begin set by another script that then executes this script, try changing to `export PPP_LOCAL="someStuff"`. Good luck.

Comment: I tried that without success... maybe I'll have to figure out how to obtain that variable from somewhere else... Stil I'd like to figure out why in sed PPP_LOCAL works great as it is in the original code.

Comment: update:
I fixed the problem using another env var and cropping it with cut to get a clean IP.
Stil the WHY is not clear to me :S

Comment: as mentioned in my first message, you don't show how you set a value for $PPP_LOCAL, so why are you suprized that your logic fails? Without a value there, you are saying `echo "" | cut ...`. right? You have to find where `PPP_LOCAL=....`, include that in the body of your Q above, and then we can help. Nowever, glad you found a work-around! Good luck.

Comment: thank you so much, without your help I couldn't make it. How can I give you rep?